# c++ return a pointer to a struct from a function

Tags: c++, pointers, struct

I am trying to have a `struct` declared in my class and then return a pointer
to that `struct` using a member function in that class, but it does not work.

Here is my code:

someClass.h:

```
class someClass
{
public:        
    someClass();
    sword* returnSword();        

    struct sword
    {
        int str;
        char name;
    };

    sword* m_sword;
};
```

someClass.cpp:

```
#include "someClass.h"

someClass::someClass()
{
    m_sword = new sword;

    m_sword->name='s';
    m_sword->str=5;
}


someClass::sword* someClass::returnSword()
{    
    return m_sword;    
}
```

In case if my code is total nonsense, please explain how can I have a struct in my class, initialize it and then return a pointer from that class pointing to that struct.

Thank you.

Comment: Define "doesn't work". What happens, and what do you expect to happen differently? I don't see anything obviously wrong in the code you've shown.

Comment: Well If I try to compile, it gives me bunch of errors, but even before, 
in the initialization of the function returnSword() function name is highlighted red with a following text.

declaration is incompatible with "<error-type> *someClass::returnSword()"

Comment: Move the definition of `sword` above that of the declaration of `returnSword`. It seems very unnecessary to dynamically allocate a `sword`, and if you do that then your class needs to follow the [Rule of Three](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4172722/241631).

Comment: I don't have much experience with pointers of this type, so when I look at the code, I feel like everything is correct, and I expect returnSword to return a pointer to the struct, but it does not work, many many errors.

Comment: Where and how do you define the sword type?

Comment: Praetorian Thank you, you are right, I had to define sword in advance, and yes dynamic allocation was actually unnecessary.

Comment: One more question. How can I do this and define my sword struct to be a private variable ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line

```
sword* returnSword();
```

is a problem. `sword` is not known at that line. Move the definition of `sword` before that line or provide a forward declaration.

```
class someClass
{
public:        
    someClass();

    struct sword
    {
        int str;
        char name;
    };

    sword* returnSword();        


    sword* m_sword;
};
```

or

```
class someClass
{
public:        
    someClass();

    struct sword;

    sword* returnSword();        

    struct sword
    {
        int str;
        char name;
    };

    sword* m_sword;
};
```

Answer (score 4):

Always post the compile errors you get. In this case:

> ```
> error: 'sword' does not name a type
>   sword* returnSword();
>   ^
> ```

OK. Why doesn't `sword` name a type? Because it hasn't been declared yet. You have to declare `sword` before you make any references to it:

```
class someClass
{
public:        
    struct sword   // <== must be declared
    {
        int str;
        char name;
    };

    someClass();
    sword* returnSword();   // <== before you use it
    // ...
};
```

Although do you really need `m_sword` to be a pointer? Could just make it a value and have `returnSword()` return a reference. That way you can't forget to `delete` it in the destructor which you didn't write...

Answer (score 0):

Using forward declaration of sword is another way to solve the problem.

```
class someClass
{
public:        
    someClass();
    struct sword; // FORWARD declaration for sword
    sword* returnSword();        

    struct sword
    {
        int str;
        char name;
    };

    sword* m_sword;
};
```